# Why does every encoded frame's size increase after I had use to set one frame to be key in intel qsv of ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, intel, h.264

I used intel's qsv to encode h264 video in ffmpeg. My av codec context settings is like as below:

```
 m_ctx->width = m_width;
    m_ctx->height = m_height;
    m_ctx->time_base = { 1, (int)fps };
    m_ctx->qmin = 10;
    m_ctx->qmax = 35;
    m_ctx->gop_size = 3000;
    m_ctx->max_b_frames = 0;
    m_ctx->has_b_frames = false;
    m_ctx->refs = 2;
    m_ctx->slices = 0;
    m_ctx->codec_id = m_encoder->id;
    m_ctx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    m_ctx->pix_fmt = m_h264InputFormat;
    m_ctx->compression_level = 4;
    m_ctx->flags &= ~AV_CODEC_FLAG_CLOSED_GOP;
    AVDictionary *param = nullptr;
    av_dict_set(&param, "idr_interval", "0", 0);
    av_dict_set(&param, "async_depth", "1", 0);
    av_dict_set(&param, "forced_idr", "1", 0);
```

and in the encoding, I set the AVFrame to be AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I when  key frame is needed:

```
  if(key_frame){
        encodeFrame->pict_type = AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I;
    }else{
        encodeFrame->pict_type = AV_PICTURE_TYPE_NONE;
    }
    avcodec_send_frame(m_ctx, encodeFrame);
    avcodec_receive_packet(m_ctx, m_packet);
   std::cerr<<"packet size is "<<m_packet->size<<",is key frame "<<key_frame<<std::endl;
```

The strange phenomenon is that if I had set one frame to AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I, then every encoded frame's size after the key frame would increase. If I change the h264 encoder to x264, then it's ok.

The packet size is as below before I call  "encodeFrame->pict_type = AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I":

```
packet size is 26839
packet size is 2766
packet size is 2794
packet size is 2193
packet size is 1820
packet size is 2542
packet size is 2024
packet size is 1692
packet size is 2095
packet size is 2550
packet size is 1685
packet size is 1800
packet size is 2276
packet size is 1813
packet size is 2206
packet size is 2745
packet size is 2334
packet size is 2623
packet size is 2055
```

If I call "encodeFrame->pict_type = AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I", then the packet size is as below:

```
packet size is 23720,is key frame 1
packet size is 23771,is key frame 0
packet size is 23738,is key frame 0
packet size is 23752,is key frame 0
packet size is 23771,is key frame 0
packet size is 23763,is key frame 0
packet size is 23715,is key frame 0
packet size is 23686,is key frame 0
packet size is 23829,is key frame 0
packet size is 23774,is key frame 0
packet size is 23850,is key frame 0
```

Comment: h.264 allows I frames that *aren't* IDR (key) frames.  Are you sure you're not forcing *all* frames to be I frames, which would explain their size?  (Use a player or editor that can show you frame types, like avidemux.  Or mpv with a custom input.conf with a frame type show-text binding for some key.)

Comment: you are right, I found that every  encoded frame is key frame by checking AVPacket's flags. So I guess the qsv encoder maybe need to reset something after it created key frame?

Comment: I have solved this issue. it's ffmpeg's bug

Comment: You could post an answer to your own question, if you have any more details, like a link to an FFmpeg trac bug number, and/or a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFMPEG doesn't reset the mfxEncodeCtrl's FrameType when encoding the next frame, it causes every frame after key frame to be IDR frame